# salesforce chatter api call examples C#

Tags: rest-api, c#

Can any body provide me with some sample calls for Salesforce data by REST API.
I have googled a lot but nothing found helpful.

I have signed up with sales force chatter.

Can i retrieve my data through API for an application . Only with me is my loggin id and password.???

How can i get the api URLs.???

How can I achieve this.???

Am using MVC 4 and C# razor engine.

I need some sample C# code Examples.

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions. 1) Clarification on how Oauth works. 2) What are the REST API URLs? 3) Some REST code examples for C#. Normally we would suggest separate topics (even though related) be separate questions. I would suggest reading a little on the topic of how to ask questions on stack exchange: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/asking . For instance, your third question about code examples is much too broad.

Comment: All are RELATED questions na?

Comment: All are related, but are too wide topics, you are most likely to get better answers for specific and precise questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For information on Oauth, I would suggest looking through the [article Force.com and OAuth 2.0](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) on developer.force.com:

For learning how to construct the URLs for making REST requests in your client application, I think the best option is to play with the REST explorer found in the workbench.developerforce.com app.

1. Go to https://workbench.developerforce.com
2. Login to your org, typically a developer edition org or sandbox while you are learning
3. Accept the OAuth "allow access" splash
4. Go to Tools > REST Explorer and start RESTing.

All of the GA REST calls should be found here in the REST explorer. The only exception is any custom Apex REST services you create. There is documentation for how to access this in the Apex code developer guide, but you can also read another good [article on creating Apex REST web services](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST).

Neither OAuth nor the construction of the actual REST calls is specific to any technology, but I can see why it would be nice to have some examples specific to Force.com to look at. Still I would expect there to be some C# code examples of calling REST web services and creating OAuth flows to be readily available in that community. So maybe take a look there.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example:
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications

Tip:  here's how to check for success and call synchronously. Just add ".Result" to the end of the call

```
                //call endpoint sync
                HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(responseString);
                }
```